# CALCULATE within the lower granularity

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a matrix that is using the fields "`Product Group`" and "`Product`" in rows.

I want to calculate the average price for the products that had sales last year. `Sales LY` is a calculated measure:

```
Sales LY = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Qty]);SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[Date]))
```

And this is the measure I'm trying to find:

```
AvgPrice= CALCULATE(DIVIDE([Turnover];[Quantity]);FILTER('Table'; [Sales LY]>0))
```

This works fine on the lower granularity (Product), but on the higher granularity (Product group) the calculation is wrong because the Product group is adding ALL the products within that Product group and I only want the ones that had sales last year.

How do I tell DAX: "Use the lower granularity"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option for situations like this is to make the higher granularities a sum of the lowest granularity values. Something like this:

```
GroupAvgPrice = CALCULATE( SUMX( VALUES( 'Table'[Product] ), [AvgPrice] ) )
```

When there is only one product in the evaluation context, this simply reduces to `[AvgPrice]`, but should work at higher granularities as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is returning the same value for all rows, both product and product group. I have a "year" filter on this page (if that's relevant).

Comment: Ah, it might not be using the filter context then. Try wrapping in a `CALCULATE` as I edited in.

Comment: It is returning a HUGE amount! Seems like it is adding multiple SUMS or something

Comment: OK, I got it using an IF statement to check wether the higher granularity is bein used!~